# TfidfVectorizer NotFittedError

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am using sklearn Pipeline and FeatureUnion to create features from text files and I want to print out the feature names.

First, I collect all transformations into a list.

```
In [225]:components
Out[225]: 
[TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, decode_error=u'strict',
         dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
         lowercase=True, max_df=0.85, max_features=None, min_df=6,
         ngram_range=(1, 1), norm='l1', preprocessor=None, smooth_idf=True,
         stop_words='english', strip_accents=None, sublinear_tf=True,
         token_pattern=u'(?u)[#a-zA-Z0-9/\\-]{2,}',
         tokenizer=StemmingTokenizer(proc_type=stem, token_pattern=(?u)[a-zA-Z0-9/\-]{2,}),
         use_idf=True, vocabulary=None),
 TruncatedSVD(algorithm='randomized', n_components=150, n_iter=5,
        random_state=None, tol=0.0),
 TextStatsFeatures(),
 DictVectorizer(dtype=<type 'numpy.float64'>, separator='=', sort=True,
         sparse=True),
 DictVectorizer(dtype=<type 'numpy.float64'>, separator='=', sort=True,
         sparse=True),
 TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, decode_error=u'strict',
         dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
         lowercase=True, max_df=0.85, max_features=None, min_df=6,
         ngram_range=(1, 2), norm='l1', preprocessor=None, smooth_idf=True,
         stop_words='english', strip_accents=None, sublinear_tf=True,
         token_pattern=u'(?u)[a-zA-Z0-9/\\-]{2,}',
         tokenizer=StemmingTokenizer(proc_type=stem, token_pattern=(?u)[a-zA-Z0-9/\-]{2,}),
         use_idf=True, vocabulary=None)]
```

For example the first component is a TfidfVectorizer() object.

```
components[0]
Out[226]: 
TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, decode_error=u'strict',
        dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=0.85, max_features=None, min_df=6,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), norm='l1', preprocessor=None, smooth_idf=True,
        stop_words='english', strip_accents=None, sublinear_tf=True,
        token_pattern=u'(?u)[#a-zA-Z0-9/\\-]{2,}',
        tokenizer=StemmingTokenizer(proc_type=stem, token_pattern=(?u)[a-zA-Z0-9/\-]{2,}),
        use_idf=True, vocabulary=None)

type(components[0])
Out[227]: sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer
```

But when I try to use the TfidfVectorizer method get_feature_names, it throws a NotFittedError

```
components[0].get_feature_names()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-228-0160deb904f5>", line 1, in <module>
    components[0].get_feature_names()

  File "C:\Users\fheng\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 903, in get_feature_names
    self._check_vocabulary()

  File "C:\Users\fheng\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 275, in _check_vocabulary
    check_is_fitted(self, 'vocabulary_', msg=msg),

  File "C:\Users\fheng\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 678, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})

**NotFittedError: TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.**
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have u used this list in a `pipeline` or `featureUnion` ? And have you called `fit()` method on them?

This error is you have not called `fit()` (ie. trained the models) and direclty trying to access the values.

Comment: Thanks. That's the problem.

Comment: @Felicia If you are satisfied, please accept the answer and/or close the question

Comment: apparently I need more reputation to close the question. How to accept the answer?

Comment: Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows).

As the author of the question, you'll see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of each answer. It'll be right below the up and down vote arrows. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow